# improve speed of sending java mails

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, email, smtp

I have written a code in Java using Java mail to send mails over smtp server. The sender and recipients email addresses as well as mail's subject and body are saved in a database(sql). However sending mails this way is quite slow. I have to send bulk mails(about 300 mails/sec). How can I improve the speed of sending the mails using multithreading ?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement;

public class mainclass {

Properties emailProperties;
Session mailSession;
MimeMessage emailMessage;



public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {
            OraclePreparedStatement pst;
            Connection con;
            String userna;
            con = connectDB.connect();
            try {
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    String sm = "SELECT * FROM EmailQueue WHERE sent = 'no'";
                    ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(sm);
                    while (res.next()) {
                        System.out.println(res.getString("from_email_address") + " " + res.getString("to_email_address"));
                        String id = res.getString("id");
                        String toEmails = res.getString("to_email_address");
                        String emailSubject = res.getString("subject");
                        String emailBody = res.getString("body");
                        String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        String fromUser = res.getString("from_email_address");
                        String fromUserEmailPassword = res.getString("password");
                        mainclass javaEmail = new mainclass();
                        javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
                        javaEmail.createEmailMessage(toEmails, emailSubject, emailBody);
                        javaEmail.sendEmail(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
                        Statement sn = con.createStatement();
                        String up = "Update EmailQueue set sent='yes' where id='"+id+"'";
                        sn.executeQuery(up);
                    }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("problem");
        }


}

public void setMailServerProperties() {

    String emailPort = "587";//gmail's smtp port

    emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

}

public void createEmailMessage(String toEmails, String emailSubject, String emailBody) throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {

    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails));


    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");//for a html email
    //emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

}

public void sendEmail(String emailHost, String fromUser, String fromUserEmailPassword) throws AddressException, MessagingException {


    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

    transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");
}

}
```

Comment: It depends where your bottleneck is, but your existing main thread could continue to read rows from the database, but send jobs to a thread pool to create your `mainclass` instances which perform the `sendMessage`.

Comment: thanx quamrana . I created a thread pool to send the mails while the main thread continued reading rows from the database.

Comment: @user3804428 can I see how you improved the speed with threads

Answer (score 2):

The key to sending high volumes of e-mail quickly is multi-threading -- both in your java code and  in the configuration of the e-mail server.

When you send e-mail via JavaMail, you are really simply submitting a message to your SMTP e-mail server.  Your SMTP server then looks up the MX address of the receiving domain (the part after the '@' in the e-mail address) to get the IP address of receiving SMTP server.  Then it begins a conversation with the receiving SMTP server that ultimately results in the message being transferred.  This process can go very slowly for a number of reasons.
- The process of looking up the IP address of the receiving server can take time
- The conversation with the receiving SMTP server may be very slow, depending on its load and policies.  Some conversations can literally take minutes.

So to speed up the throughput of your e-mail application you should:
1) Make sure you have a caching name server local to your SMTP server.  This will make its process of identifying the IP of the receiving SMTP go much more quickly.  Basically, a caching name server remembers past lookup requests locally, so subsequent requests for the same domain are much quicker (possible 100x quicker).  In other words, once you look up the receiving IP address for 'gmail.com', you don't need to look it up again until its TTL expires.  On Red Hat linux, you can configure bind to be a caching nameserver via 'yum install caching-nameserver'.

2) Configure your SMTP server to have *many* threads.  Since most of the time, your SMTP server will be waiting on other servers to carry on their side of the 'conversation', it can efficiently carry on hundreds of conversations at once. I use Postfix because it is fast and reliable.  By default, Postfix is configured to have 100 simultaneous SMTP processes.  I raise this to 300 or more.  In Postfix, you can configure this process limit using the default_process_limit setting.

3) Tune your SMTP server to take into account that some receiving servers will be very slow or completely non-responsive.  For example, Postfix by default is configured to wait for 300 seconds (five minutes!) for the receiving server to respond to its initial 'HELO'.  I cut this time way down, to 100 seconds by setting the configuration option of smtp_helo_timeout=100s.  Messages that are not successfully sent because of slow receiving servers are simply queued by your SMTP server to retry later on.

4) Use Multi-threading in your use of JavaMail.  I have sped things up many factors of 10 creating multi-threading in my Java code.  THis way, there are many conversations going on with my SMTP server at once.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading the process of sending mail will just break down your mail server with thousands of requests.

When you are sending an e-mail (with JavaMail for example), you are just submitting a new mail to your mail server. It's the mail server that will actually send the mail to the recipients. There is nothing you can do on the Java side to improve the speed of delivery.